# Google Cloud VM Windows instance wallpaper Snapshot Time:

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud, snapshot

I am managing two VM instances in Google Cloud and have a question about the Snapshot Time: field.  Where is this coming from and does it mean that an actual snapshot was taken?  In both cases 'gcloud compute snapshots list' finds no snapshots.

Thanks.

Jon

Comment: Are you referring to the Snapshot "creation time" field? and could you provide more explanation on what it meant by " In both cases 'gcloud compute snapshots list' finds no snapshots." as it is unclear. Are you trying to apply some kind of a filter using the snapshot "creation time"?

Comment: Yes, I could see why the text could be misleading; the question title has wallpaper but not the question text.  So on the wallpaper there is a Snapshot date and time, that seems to get updated whenever I log on to the VM instance, however I see no snapshots listed.  So the distilled question is:  Is gcloud taking some kind of hidden snapshot, or is the wallpaper snapshot date and time something else?

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing the snapshot time like in [BgInfo](https://www.askvg.com/bginfo-show-system-hardware-and-software-information-on-windows-desktop-background) with GCP Windows [Persistent Disk Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-persistent-disk-snapshot). There are no hidden snapshots gcloud would attempt unless you schedule it somehow for your VM. You can [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/snapshots/list) available snapshots along with the time they were created.

Comment: Now I have finally been able to create snapshots for both VMs, the snapshot time on the wallpaper reflects the date and time they were taken.  Where the date and time was coming from before is anyone's guess?  Maybe gcloud populated it by default.

Comment: Does it get updated when you login back to your VM? or it always shows the actual snapshot creation time unchanged??

Comment: It looks like this wallpaper banner appears when you connect to your server using "Windows Remote Desktop"; and not when using "Chrome RDP". Do you agree?